# Potential problems with call chaining

Tags: java, methods, notation

In the snippet of code below, I'm using a class to get a reference to an instance of BookList. This class has a getBook() method which returns an instance of a Book from a String representing an isbn code. The instruction is run in the doGet() method of a HttpServlet.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
Book book = GlobalVar.bookList.getBook( request.getParameter("isbn") );
//
}
```

What potential problems do you see in using shorthand notation in this context ?

P.S: The Global class is going to be replaced with a ServletContext.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "shorthand".

Comment: what do you mean by shorthand?

Comment: I'm not sure what to call it (if anyone has any suggestions I'm all ears) but I'd call it condensed code as an alternative.

For example, the line of code above could be decomposed so that you first get a reference to a BookList and then you get the value of the Parameter isbn to finally get the Book.

In between each of these, some checking can take place which is something I am probably making a bad habit of skipping by writing everything in one line.

Comment: Ah. I think the generic term is "call chaining". If the calls along the way are "foolproof" or report errors by way of exceptions, then there's nothing wrong with chaining. If you should be checking values and stati, and especially if you are seeing inexplicable errors, then you should expand your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say **NullPointerExceptions**. What happends if the client, doing the HTTP GET request, has no paramated named "isbn". Is the getBook implemented in way that it supports null as an argument?

Comment: getBook() returns the get() from a HashMap. Javadoc isn't clear what happens when you do a get() with a null but testing shows that it has no consequence. My reflex would be to test if the instance of book is null afterwards. Ideally, I should develop a consistant style that will avoid Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The request may not have a parameter "isbn".

Comment: Indeed. This will cause a NullPointerException as Roger has pointed out if the value of book isn't checked. I already have the habit of checking values that are obtained by a method so that isn't a problem. I just wish there was a checklist out there of good practises to apply.